# Alert on page indexing in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where I use page-indexing. If user navigates to next page I need to give an alert like "Make sure you updated the page before you move" and a pop up should display. If yes is clicked it should go to another page or if cancel is clicked it has to stay in the same page.

I am using this js, but the alert comes often if any button in the page is clicked. How can I display message only when paging is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isPaging;
    $(".myPagingButton").on("click", function () {
        isPaging = true;
    });

    function goodbye(e) {
        if (!isPaging) {
            return;
        }
        isPaging = false;
        if (!e) e = window.event;

        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = 'Make sure you have updated the page before navigation?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to appear for the paging buttons, than set a flag when the buttons are clicked.

HTML:

```
<a class="myPagingButon" href="example.html">Paging</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var isPaging;
$(function(){
    $(".myPagingButon").on("click", function() { console.log("click");
        isPaging = true;
    });
});

function goodbye(e) {
    if (!isPaging) { 
        return; 
    }
    isPaging = false;
    return 'Dialog text here.';
}
window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbGaq/2/)

Comment: But I don't see the alerts coming up when I click the paging. If I understood your answer, I just put your answer in my page and tested from my e.cancelbubble statement.

Comment: Works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/fbGaq/ Did you actually change the class name in the selector?

Comment: I updated the post with my try. Can you pls take a look.

Comment: Because you are calling it before the buttons are on the page most likely. You need to use document ready. Updated code...

Comment: Can you help me frame the js as I am new and learning to do. I don't get it completely.

Comment: I am not sure what you are not getting, the basic code above works how you want it to. You need to apply it to your code by adjusting the classes.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){ 
        goodbye(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I get the button id for paging?

Comment: It's just example. You can select it by class - getElementByClassName, or tag - getElementByTagName.